# How to deploy website from dev to staging from localhost to remote server using composer

Tags: craft3, aws

I want to upload all my Craft files along with the database to an Ubuntu server using composer. This server is an EC2 instance of AWS.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a course on CraftQuest regarding deployment of Craft CMS you might want to check out: https://craftquest.io/courses/deploying-craft-cms-3

For my personal workflow, I develop locally then push my codebase to Github. Since my servers are built using Laravel Forge, I have it set up to deploy my code to my server, which can be an AWS server, Digital Ocean, or any number of places.

For some sites, I use a more robust deployment service. I've used both Envoyer.io and Deploybot to do that. I wrote a post on the Deploybot set up I used. You can find that post here: https://supergeekery.com/blog/laravel-forge-and-deploy-bot

Answer (score 1):

I think this deploy-bot / buddy stuff is a bit overkill.
I love to use Laravel Forge and for this u have to pay, when u want to build your business on it (for many clients).

Like I do with my [statamic sites](https://v2.statamic.com/knowledge-base/forge) I think u can just do it the same way with your Craft 3 Github repo.

Deploy-bot / buddy / envoyer is good for continuous deployment where u want to have zero downtime. But this is just for crucial apps with a huge amount of users. Keep in mind that is will cost you additional money.

For the most websites its completely ok when its down for a few minutes when u deploy new stuff every few weeks.

Comment: we also use laravel forge with quick deployment. pushing to the master branch -> done, deployed. ans for having everything in sync: craft scripts.

Comment: I use 'git checkout . ' in my deploy script - to avoid merge conflicts. How do you solve that?

Answer (score 1):

I use https://deployer.org/ which is a php package you can run from the command line.

It's great if you're looking for a free, zero-downtime solution to deploy your sites. The downside however is that it's a bit harder to set up compared to paying tools. You need to be comfortable using the command line and have some basic understanding of git / ssh / ...

Comment: Hey - nice - thats free, or do I miss something ;). Looks simply and good. Maybe I try it out sometimes. Thank you.